# Break loop and catch remaining items count

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to develop a feature.

There are users who like a post, however, after naming the only three users, I'd like to capture the rest into a number like so:

Jeff, John, Jane and 45 others liked this post.

This is what I have so far:

```
@foreach($post->liked as $liked){{ $loop->first ? '' : ', ' }}{{ $liked->user->name }}@if($loop->iteration == 1) {{ $liked->count() }} @break @endif @endforeach
```

Can anyone please shed light on how this can be done? Sorry, I'll be trying to figure it out in the meantime but just thought I'd ask in case I get stuck on it for too long.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:: I added $liked->count() which shows the number of likes, but how can I remove the number of the users that have already liked the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the remaining item counts use `$loop->remaining`, it's inbuild feature of laravel.
You can check more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade).

Comment: This was immensely helpful in putting the finishing touches to the feature. Thank you!

Comment: @user123 Glad, please accept it as the correct answer for your query, so it will be helpful to others too.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($post->liked as $liked)
{{ $loop->first ? '' : ', ' }}
{{ $liked->user->name }}
@if($loop->iteration == 1) and {{ $liked->count() - 1}} others @break 
@endif 
@endforeach
```

Use $liked->count() and subtract the number of users you already want displayed.